is it possible to source ros setup.bash and make effect within python script
normally i do it like:
source /ros/setup.bash && python myscript.py

but i wish to make it easier, like just python myscript.py, i.e.
is it possible do the source /ros/setup.bash within a python script, then no need do that in terminal before run the py script?
I tried in myscript.py
import os
os.system("source /ros/setup.bash")
os.popen("source /ros/setup.bash")  

import subprocess
subprocess.call("source /ros/setup.bash") 
subprocess.Popen("source /ros/setup.bash") 

import rclpy

# my code


but none works, always get error like
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rclpy'

which means the ros env not loaded.

I don't know, what setup.bash is doing, but in your approach, the source happens in a child process of your Python script, and any changes you are doing in this script are of course not visible in your Python program.  Why don't you put your source && python stuff into a shell function?
